# Execute multi-line PostgreSQL script containing stored procedure call with IN/INOUT Parameters using java

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a special case, in which the following PostgreSQL script is required to be called from java:

```
do
        $$
        DECLARE
        xx VARCHAR(200);
        xy VARCHAR(200);
        xz VARCHAR(200);
        yy VARCHAR(200);
        BEGIN
        xx := ?;
        xy := ?;
        call database_procedure(yy, yz, xx, xy);
        ? := yy;
        ? := yz;
        END;
        $$
```

This script is passed to CallableStatement in the following way, and the Input/Output parameters are binded with the callable statement.

```
CallableStatement cs = pgConn.prepareCall(sqlScript);
cs.setString(1,"param1");
cs.setString(2,"value2");
cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
```

I get the issue on the line

```
cs.setString(1,"param1");
```

Issue: **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.**

Upon research i have found that, this issue is because the cs.setString is unable to find question mark(or parameter place holder).
Also, When i try simple query as following, it works.

```
CallableStatement cs = pgConn.prepareCall("call database_procedure(?,?,?,?)");
```

But according to my current scenario, I need a solution to executing the whole script as i mentioned, instead of only one call, because in different scenarios we are assigning values to out parameters based on the data returned by the procedure and so on.
Kindly help, so that, somehow the IN/INOUT parameters are passed to the sql script mentioned above.

Comment: `DO` is an anonymous function it does not take parameters. Also it cannot be called.  If you want to do this create a proper function or procedure.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Alright, so shall i remove DO from the script and keep the $$ sign?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver still giving the same error.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver actually this script is a vdb level stored procedure.

Comment: You need to create a full function/procedure per [Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) or [Procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html).

Comment: why the do block? Why not call the stored procedure directly from Java?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's indeed a logical question, but in my case, i have separate layer of vdb level stored procedure and database level stored procedures. The above sql script is for vdb level stored procedure, which is calling the database level SP. This sql script above in other cases also contain conditional statements and exception handling, which is the reason it is a whole DO block.

Comment: What is stopping you from creating a named stored procedure with the script, and then calling the stored procedure?

Comment: @Andreas are you talking about creating a named procedure with this script on the database?

Comment: @Andreas can you please tell me more about your solution?

Comment: @Andreas that sounds interesting, though,

Comment: Yes, create a stored procedure with the 4 declared variables as parameters, so you can call it using `prepareCall("{call my_procedure(?,?,?,?)}")` --- Your current script is however a very bad example, because you can just call `prepareCall("{call database_procedure(?,?,?,?)}")`, since there is no extra logic at all.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, current script doesnot contain any other logic. i posted it here because it was simple to see.
Thank you!

Comment: Still open to see more recommendations.. as i also want a solution for the "?" issue.